# Invoking a ViewComponent, using reflection

Tags: c#, async-await

Attempting to Invoke a ViewComponent using reflection, I cannot figure out the final steps to get a basic string from the view component result.  I want to return the string from the method, I am not sure what to do next. Seems this should not be that complicated.

The reason I have to do this; is the components are coming from a different Assembly and using the full namespace does not work `OtherApplication.ViewComponentLibrary.ViewComponent`

This is a Razor Component Libary (RCL) and will be passed the name of the view components to invoke.  The view Components will be built in different RCL and referenced. Both RCL's will be used in a MVC application in the middle.

Thank you.

```
public Task<string> InvokeAsync()
{
  var c = _componentInvokeHelper.GetComponentModel(Name);
  Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(c.AssemblyFullName); 
  Type t = asm.GetType(c.FullName);
  var methodInfo = t.GetMethod(c.InvokeMethod.Name);

  try
  {
    var viewComponent = (ViewComponent)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(_serviceProvider, t);
    var parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(ParamObjJson);
            
    if (methodInfo.ReturnType.BaseType == typeof(Task))
    {
      var method = (Task<IViewComponentResult>)methodInfo.Invoke(viewComponent, new object[] { parameters });
      method.ContinueWith(task =>
      {
        var r1 = task.Result;
       }).Wait();
      return null; What do I do here
    }
    else
    {
      var method = (Task<IViewComponentResult>)methodInfo.Invoke(viewComponent, new object[] { parameters });
      return null; //What do I do here
    }   
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  string e = ex.Message;
}

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do something like this

```cs
var methodRes = methodInfo.Invoke(viewComponent, new object[] { parameters });

if (methodRes is Task<IViewComponentResult> task)
{
    var res = await methodRes;
    
    return ConvertIViewComponentResultToString(res);
}
else if (methodRes is IViewComponentResult comRes)
{
    return ConvertIViewComponentResultToString(res);
}
else 
{
    // error handling or return default value
}
```

So you just await the return value of the method if it is a Task and simply get the result. Remeber that you need to declare the method as `async` so you can use the `await` keyword.

Since you didn't showed how the type `IViewComponentResult`  gets converted to a string I assumed somekind of method `ConvertIViewComponentResultToString`.

Comment: My main question was how do you convert the view component result to a string.